# How to manually post back when in a repeater?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am fairly new to asp.net webforms so I am open to suggestions of any kind.

I am listing products with a repeater.
With every product the  looks something like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <div class="actionbutton_normal actionbutton_cart" onmouseover="actnbut_hover($(this))" onmouseout="actnbut_out($(this))" onclick="actnbut_click($(this))">
      <asp:CheckBox Checked="false" class="actnbox_hidden" ID="chkCart" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
   </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

As you can see the checkbox itself is hidden and it is used to represent the state of the icon.
I modify the checkbox's Checked attribute in javascript in the actnbut_click function. The problem with this is that checking the box in javascript does not activate the autopostback, (and I think it does not even make it into the viewstate, but I'm not sure). I tried to post back manually but I'm not able to figure out how to do it properly as the checkbox's ID is generated by the repeater.

All in all I want this functionality: there are a few items, under them are buttons (favorite, add to cart, select for comparsion, etc) with nice hover and click animations on them. If I click them I want serverside logic to be executed (depending on which button I clicked under which item, for example add to cart should add the specific item to the cart panel, or clicking on fav should access the database and increment the item's fav value by one, and add the item to the users favorites), but preserving the state of the objects on the page, including the buttons' state (clicked or not).

Which would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call __doPostBack(controlName, options) from javascript.

Comment: The problem is, that I'm not sure about the controlName, since I'm in a repeater and it is somehow autogenerated.

Comment: Use options to pass commandName and commandValue. To test, create simple page with a repeater and check box inside it. Add commandName and commandValue, to check box, and see .net generated script from page source. It will give an idea how repeater is posted.